# Clearing Parent and keeping rotation

Tags: parent

I'm trying to clear parents of some mirrored and seperated objects and even if I clear parent while keeping transform, the scale and rotation of the objects still change and warp the objects which destroys all the work. I don't quite understand how to get this to work.

Comment: did you use non-uniform scaling in any of the parent objects?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's non-uniform scaling now that you mentionned it, the difficulty is that if I ctrl+a the scale it breaks everything aswell, a somewhat tricky situation. Lander lead me to an answer of his that seems to be the solution, quite a complicated workaround but it's probably the best way as of now.

Comment: Yes that is a huge problem in 3D rotation + non-uniform scaling almost always leads to shearing. In Blender unfortunately this is a known issue, but there are no intentions of fixing it.